# Throw worning for props in vue3 when using with typescript generic

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I facing such strange warning. 
I defined non-Array types look like posted sample codes.  
But, Vue3 was throwing warnings. 
Have some solutions?? 
or I got some miss takes?

Simply, I was defined `modelValue` type look like `T | T[] | undefined` 
But, Vue3 detected `Null | Array`. 
Then, How a `T` are have been ignored??

I'm using Nuxt3, Vue3, composition api

```
// types/index.d.ts
type ItemType { [key: string]: any } | string | boolean
```

```
// CSelect.vue
<template><div>{{/* contents - It's not a key on this Topic */}}</div></template>
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends ItemType">
defineProps<{
  items: T[]
  modelValue: T | T[] | undefined
}>()
</script>
```

```
// create.vue - how i used
<template>
  <div class="create">
    <div class="title-area">
      <CForm>
        <InputTemplate>
          {{/* This CSelect components are Throw warnings by v-model */}}
          <CSelect 
            v-model="data.category"
            class="nft-input"
            :items="categoryItems"
          />
        </InputTemplate>
      </CForm>
    </div>
  <div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const categoryItems = computed(() => ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'])
const data = reactive({ category: String(categoryItems.value[0]) })
</script>
```

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected Null | Array, got String with value "Limited". 
  at <CSelect modelValue="Limited" onUpdate:modelValue=fn class="input"  ... > 
  at <InputTemplate title="Category" > 
  at <CForm modelValue=false onUpdate:modelValue=fn class="inputs-area"  ... > 
  at <Create onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <Anonymous key="/member/99/create" routeProps= {Component: {…}, route: {…}} pageKey="/member/99/create"  ... > 
  at <Anonymous > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <Default > 
  at <Anonymous key="default" name="default" hasTransition=false > 
  at <Anonymous > 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <App key=1 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

Comment: Don't pass a `modelvalue` as a prop. You won't be able to use it because it's read-only. Just use `<CSelect v-model="value" ...` and get to know how to bind `$attrs` in your component to select tag element.

Comment: @Mises Hi, i missed, How i used. I added that use case. Thank you, for your opinion.

Comment: @Mises could you give me a second? I'll re edit, How i write my CSelect component

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component `create.vue` has no `setup` and `lang="ts"`. You're passing to a child `v-model` and `class` with no `:` so they aren't props, they are attributes. `div` element will have them because he is a root element.

**Example how to use attributes:**

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <label :for="label">{{label}}</label>
      <input v-bind="$attrs" :id="label" :value="$attrs.modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
   </div>
</template>
<script setup>
defineProps(['label'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

`v-bind` assign all attributes to one element.

I'm not using generic in components, so I can just tell you stop! User don't care about generic, and you are not experienced programmer to build UI libraries for different programmers.

Comment: You are correct. i don't have many experience for build UI libraries. but i hope to clean up this issue.
Actually, my question is not need to use `$attrs`, and child component's contents. cuz parent component has been initized correct value(on my thinking). But, Vue loader thrown type warning. I think it's a kind of bug.

Comment: @tryAll Your code confuse because you are passing `$attrs` to a child. If you want to pass props, all attributes should have `:` before.

Comment: hmm.. I think not need when you hope to using some attributes with that is a fixed string type or true. Vue will be merge automatically with native html attributs. that is on [Vue documents](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance.)

Comment: if i defined multi root component, `$attrs` are must throw, but in this case not need to do.
[reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes)

Comment: @tryAll Root DOM element gets automatically attributes unless you use `v-bind="$attrs"` somewhere else. In your child component `v-model` have `<div>` element.

Comment: @tryAll There you go, I changed it. I just tried to show you how you can pass attributes to nested elements.

Comment: ah i understood, what you hope to talk to me. Thank you.

Comment: "I'm not using generic in components, so I can just tell you stop! User don't care about generic" this is actually a pretty terrible advice in general. Generics are awesome and can enhance the code. You should not encourage people to stop using them in general. There are users that will care about them. It makes testing so much easier